# How to fetch and pass data {objects} with use()?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, jsx, next.js13

*Using React with Next.JS 13*

I am trying to fetch data from an API and pass it to a component. Then the component maps through it and displays it.

The API returns an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "category": {},
        "results": [{...}]
    }
]
```

The page.tsx where I want to do the fetching contains this (simplified) structure:

```
import SearchResults from "./SearchResults.tsx";
import { use } from "react";

async function search() {
  let res = await fetch(`http://api:port/search`);
  return res;
}

export default function Results({ data }) {
  let searchResults = use(search());

  return <SearchResults data={searchResults} />;
}
```

I've stripped out types, interfaces, and irrelevant content.

For the component file, we have:

```
export interface SearchResult {
  skillName: string;
  ...}

export interface Response {
  category: string;
  results: SearchResult[];
}

export interface SearchResultsProps {
  data: [];
}

const SearchResults = ({ data }: SearchResultsProps) => {
  return (
      {data.response.map((i, index) => ( 
        <div key={index}>
          <h2>{i.category}</h2>
          {i.results.map((r, resultIndex) => (
            <SearchCard
              key={`result.${index}.${resultIndex}`}
              skillName={r.skillName}
              ...
            />
          ))}
        </div>
     ))}
  );
};

export default SearchResults;
```

I tried binding the response to `data` in a few different ways, but the component always states that data.results is undefined. Inspecting the network tab in the browser (when I add "use client" to the code) shows the API returns the correct data. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I made a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/zfww9BHS) with the full file version, in case I cut out something important.

Comment: Can you console.log `res` in your search function? Don't you need to call res.json() to get the actual response?

Comment: @Micky The API already returns JSON, but I did try parsing it with .json() as well. Logging res, and not data, returns https://pastebin.com/Rqq9dsxs. Logging data returns [object Object]

Comment: That looks like an http response not the actual JSON you want. Can you change it to `const data = await res.json();` and then `console.log(data);`?

Comment: @Micky That returns: [ { category: { id: x, name: '...' }, results: [[Object]] }, { category: { id: y, name: '...'}, results: [[Object]] } ]. Does results being listed as an [Object] make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using answer format so I explain better.
Now that you have your actual result by extracting the JSON

```
async function search() {
  let res = await fetch(`http://api:port/search`);
  return await res.json();
}
```

Now you can start mapping out your data based on the results you posted in your comment.

```
[ { category: { id: x, name: '...' }, results: [[Object]] }, { category: { id: y, name: '...'}, results: [[Object]] } ]
```

This would look something like the below

```
{i.map((item, index) => (
   <SearchCard
     key={index}
     skillName={item.results.skillName}
     ...
   />
))}
```

Map will operate on each item in the array. So the first array from your example contains a `category` and a `results` key. You will glean the rest of your data from those sub objects.

I suggest that you reach out to the documentation provided by your API. They should be able to provide additional details on how the data should look. It's possible that `results` is not being returned as valid JSON which might be the reason why it looks like `results: [[Object]]. If that is the case you will have to work with them or unwrap the string yourself.

I hope this helps!